# How can I dynamically change destination in Talend ESB route?

Tags: routes, talend

I have a simple Talend route:

> cMQConnectionFactory (mq config) -- cJMS (reads from mq) --> cHttp (send to REST on another machine)

I want to be able to change cHttp destination (Uri) basing on messages content. Message is a JSON with a field "address" to which I need to send the message.

Do Talend routes allow to change destination dynamically?

*Or am I misunderstanding the concept completely and routes need to be created individually for each pair of message "producer-consumer" ?*

Comment: You should be able to do that by extracting data with a JSONPath/Xpath Query (put it in a header for example, through cSetHeader component). After that you can use your new header ${header.yourName} in the cHttp component.

Comment: @Corentin Could you please add some details? I'm really new to this stuff. I have a json as string from MQ, with the field "address" that is an url of REST service I need to call .. how should it be rigged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a cHttp with `uri = "foobar" to find easily the setting in the generated code. You can see it is set inside

```
public void configure() throws java.lang.Exception {
     ...
     from(
            "timer:cTimer_1" + "?period=" + 2500 + "&repeatCount=" + 10
                    + "&delay=" + 1000)
            .routeId("Route_cTimer_1")
            .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("GET")).to("foobar")

            .id("Route_cHttp_1");
}
```

Unfortunatly, this is done during the initialisation, so the value is constant (like almost everything in Mediation)

Solutions :

**1) With a specific list of destination**

You can use a `cMessageRouter` to act as a switch to send the message to the correct cHttp (this mean one `cHttp` per destination)

**2) With unknown destination**

You could use a Job to be manage that dynamic destination to generate your URI and send a request from there. I am not sure you can get the value from the job either (for the same reason)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it seems routes can be only "static" (defined in compile-time).

Comment: @Kromster defined during the beginning of the runtime actually. You can use Context variable and set a different environnement (with default value) or even use a cConfig to load values from a properties file (can remember how we have done that...) and this will load values before the configure method, but you will need to restart the route if you want to update anything. So it's not really on runtime but it is still not fully dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a cDSLProcessor component. Set up some headers dynamically from your data, then in DSLProcessor write `.to("http://"+echange.getIn().getHeader("myheader")`